# concatenate values from several fields into one

Tags: acumatica

I'm looking for help, I want to concatenate the type value and tax category value within the description field.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways in which you can go about this.

1. Given that there are 2 fields involved in your concatenation, and any of them could be changed at any given moment, you could manage the logic in the `RowUpdated` event. In which case, you should filter by the specific fields to be considered in order to prevent this logic to be executed for any other field.

For instance:

```
protected virtual void InventoryItem_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    InventoryItem newRow = (InventoryItem)e.Row;
    InventoryItem oldRow = (InventoryItem)e.OldRow;
    if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<InventoryItem.itemType>(e.Row, e.OldRow) 
            || !sender.ObjectsEqual<InventoryItem.taxCategoryID>(e.Row, e.OldRow))
    {

            //Add concatenation logic
            sender.SetValue<InventoryItem.descr>(newRow, "NEW CONCATENATED VALUE");
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you have all the logic centralized in the one place.

2. As an alternative approach, you could use the `FieldUpdated` events from **ItemType** and **TaxCategoryID**.

Regardless of the option that you select, both fields should have the **CommitChanges** property set to true in the ASPX in order to have the logic executed immediately after taking the focus out of the field

Comment: Great, It works correctly, I took the first option, one more thing, I'm trying to concatenate a value from the product attributes but I can't access to it. Would I need to use joins to another tables?

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado if the proposed answer is working correctly, please kindly accept the response. As for the new question, please create a new stackoverflow post to keep the topics separated

Answer (score 0):

Create a customization.  In the customization project, go to Database Script, create a sql script.  Add the following command

```
 update inventoryitem set descr = case when charindex(' type: ',descr)>0 
then left(descr,charindex(' type: ',descr)) 
else descr end + ' type: ' + case 
when itemtype = 'F' then 'Finished Good' 
when itemtype = 'M' then 'Component Part' 
when itemtype = 'A' then 'SubAssembly' 
when itemtype = 'N' then 'Non-Stock Item' 
when itemtype = 'L' then 'Labor' 
when itemtype = 'S' then 'Service' 
when itemtype = 'C' then 'Charge' 
else 'Expense' end + ' tax: ' + TaxCategoryID
```

Publish the customization whenever you want to update the values.

Comment: Question doesn't involve actually updating the database value, I think it might be more appropriate to only change the displayed value (with concatenation) while keeping the item description unchanged.